# How is it that a mapreduce pipeline can run longer than 10 minutes?

Tags: mapreduce, appengine-pipeline

MapReduce tasks are run within a parent pipeline, and of course we all know they can run for a very long time. But at the same time, the pipeline api documents that a pipeline must complete within 10 minutes (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/wiki/Python). What is the proper way to understand this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That pipeline documentation is really old... when it was written, tasks were limited to 10-mins.   Now you can configure a non-default modules (used to be called a "backend") using basic/manual scaling that will allow a task to run for 24hrs

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class 
(NOTE: if you run a task on an auto-scaled module, it will still be limited to 10-mins)

The entire pipeline doesn't have to be limited to 24hrs though.  The "root" pipeline (the first task that runs) can yield many child pipelines, and those each can further yield other pipelines... each pipeline is a task that has to run within the allotted time (10mins or 24hrs)... when it is done, it signals the parent to wake-up and finish... so the overall pipeline could run for days or months or whatever

We have our app split into two modules, one for the front-end (default, auto-scaled) that handles web requests, and one for the "back end" (basic scaling) that runs all of our tasks

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's something else. I had a discussion earlier today in the comments section of the following web page that clarified it for me: http://sookocheff.com/posts/2015-05-19-app-engine-pipelines-part-three-fan-in-fan-out/

Basically, it's not the pipeline that needs to be finalized within the task deadline (10 minutes). But rather it's the run method that needs to finish within the task deadline. Mapreduce is able to do that by slicing and sharding, and the root pipeline just waits for the complete callback.

Comment: yeah, each task has to finish within the allotted time... and a pipeline is a bunch of tasks being run and pulled together at a root.  The root doesn't sit there idle while the children are running, it spawns them all and stops, then when the children are all done the root "wakes up" and can complete (could be DAYs later). I don't know why that guy keeps saying "10 minutes" in the discussion when that's only for auto-scaled modules (as I pointed out, basic/manual scaled modules can go for 24hrs)